# Firefox: unwanted click events triggered by HTML select/options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, firefox

I have a `select` element with `option`s to choose from. Choosing an `option` triggers a callback (in my real project it is a function that creates a new element on the page and loads content into it using an ajax call). I can do it in Firefox either by the `select`'s `change` event handler, or by the `option`s' `click` event handler (see my code below). This all works perfectly when you do nothing but choose an option and click on it.

The problem starts when you get out of the `select` by clicking outside it. For example, if you open the dropdown by a click, but then step through some `option`s by using the arrows on the keyboard, then clicking outside the `select` produces a `select.change` (that's fine) and an `option.click` event (that's not so fine, since nobody clicked on an `option`). I would still be okay with that (although that gesture means abandoning the element rather than selecting an option), but when you actually click on something that also triggers an event (in real life, for example, creating or destroying elements on the page), it produces a mess.

Speaking of the sample code below, what I want to achieve is that, by *one* click, either the `div` or an `option` be `click`ed, and never both. (I don't care about the `select.change`.)

I have tried both catching and unbinding `blur` and `focusout` events of the `select`, to no avail.

How can I prevent Firefox from triggering an `option.click` when the user simply abandons the `select`?

Opening the select, moving around with the arrows on the keyboard, then clicking on the div ("click on this div") produces the following output on the JS console:

```
select was changed
option1 was clicked
div was clicked
```

I'm using Firefox 50.1. jQuery 1.4.2 is provided by the portal I am to use.

Code:

```js
$('.myDiv')
    .click( function (e) {
        console.log('div was clicked');
        return false;
    })
;
$('.mySelect')
    .change( function (e) {
        console.log('select was changed');
        return false;
    })
;
$('.mySelect option')
    .click( function (e) {
        console.log($(this).val() + ' was clicked');
        return false;
    })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='myDiv'>click on this div</div>
<select class='mySelect'>
<option disabled='disabled' selected='selected'>Please select an option</option>
<option>option1</option>
<option>option2</option>
<option>option3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: just add e.preventDefault() to your function

Comment: @Eric Since I'm using jQuery, `return false` should imply `preventDefault`, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false). However, I also tried stating it explicitly, with no luck. Apparently the problem is not with the default action, but with triggering the event itself. I suspect that only a workaround can help, if anything.

Comment: Another failed experiment: `offsetX` and `offsetY` of `option.click` events give the same constant values both inside and outside the select. `select.click` also gives the same constants for the offsets if the `option`s do not prevent the event from bubbling up.

Comment: Further experiment shows that the problem is not jQuery-specific. Firefox shows the exact same behavior if I get rid of all the JS code, and put the `console.log`s into `onClick` attributes inside the HTML tags: 
`<div class='myDiv' onClick="console.log('div was clicked');">some other functionality</div>
<select class='mySelect' onClick="console.log('select was clicked');">
<option disabled='disabled' selected='selected'>Please select an option</option>
<option onClick="console.log('option1 was clicked');">option1</option>
etc.
</select>`

Answer (score 0):

onclick event on OPTION tag will fail on most versions of IE, Safari and Chrome: [reference](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html).

Comment: Yeah, I am aware. I'm doing this solely for Firefox.